# Algo to divide earth into fixed regions. Then an algo to see which regions a given latitude, longitude, and radius overlap

Tags: algorithm, math, geolocation, geometry, geospatial

To create a real-time socket/channel, I need discrete values, like a chat room with a name (room 1, room 2, etc.), where a user has a finite number of predefined options they can choose/subscribe to.

For my new project, the real time stuff is happening on a map. So users send Latitude, Longitude, and Radius, any event that happens in that field of view will be sent to them in real time. This is really continuos (each users values are likely to be unique), so it’s much harder to predefine sockets/channels for a user.

Here is my current idea of how to make it work.

1. Break the globe down into static, fixed-size squares. (any width, maybe about 500m^2). These are now our discrete sockets/channels.
2. When a user send lat, lng, radius, find the squares that their map covers, add them to each channel/socket
3. Certain spots that are in a “square”, may not be in the users actual view, so the client-side would have to check each update and display it if it’s relevant, or else ignore it.

[image: Here is an image to demonstrate]

- Blue dot is the user
- We would add the user to channels 16,17,18, 26,27,28,36,37,38.
- Both the red and yellow dot (in square 16), would be pushed to the user in real-time.
- Yellow dot is relevant and in-view, so it would be added
- Red dot is not in the users view, so it is ignored.

My questions:
1. Is there a better way to do this?

2. Is there a name for this type of issue/problem?
3. Is there an existing solution/algorithm/library for this type of problem?
4. How can I…

   a. divide the globe into fixed size, uniform, numbered squares.

   b. given a lng, lat, radius - calculate which squares are relevant to that user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a name for this type of issue/problem?

Spatial indexing

> Is there an existing solution/algorithm/library for this type of problem?

I'm sure there are others (and maybe even one that works on squares) but this popped to mind:

http://www.skyserver.org/htm/Old_default.aspx

Uses triangles instead of squares, but it's the same idea.  Not sure if it supports a radius-search per se, but you could do a coarse query and refine, as you do in your example.

An alternative, if you're just trying to find the nearest users, you could do something like a kd-tree with nearest-neighbors search (this is a departure from your idea, but I'm not sure what the relative cost of having a huge number of socket/channels would be - you could create them on demand this way, based on the ID of the triangle at level K - where K is based on whatever smallest range you choose)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Nearest_neighbour_search